# Excel find smaller values than x > identify date/time and paste it

Tags: excel

I am having data (image below) and task is to find values <3, identify what date and hour is and paste dates, hours in another spreadsheet of that cells. Does any have ideas?

[image: Screenshot]

> 

```
Option Explicit
> 
> Sub CopyPaste()
> 
> Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Row As Long, Column As Long, x
> As Long Dim wb As Workbook Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet Dim
> SearchRange As Range, Cell As Range
> 
> Set wb = ThisWorkbook Set ws = wb.Sheets("DataHorizontal") 'the sheet
> in which your data is Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Overview") 'the sheet where
> you want your result
> 
> LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row LastCol = ws.Cells(1,
> Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
> 
> Set SearchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
> 
> x = 27
> 
> For Each Cell In SearchRange
>     Row = Cell.Row
>     Column = Cell.Column
>     If Cell.Value < -3 Or Cell.Value > 3 Then
>         'Output is placed in 2 columns, A for date, B for time
>         ws2.Cells(x, 5).Value = ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value 'Copy-paste Date
>         ws2.Cells(x, 6).Value = ws.Cells(1, Column).Value 'Copy-Paste Time
>         x = x + 1
>     End If Next Cell
> 
> End Sub
```

[Output with <-3 or >3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tmp7u.png)
[Dataset more left columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p44LS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a macro to do so.

Code example

```
    Option Explicit

Sub CopyPaste()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long, Row As Long, Column As Long, x As Long
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim SearchRange As Range, Cell As Range

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("input") 'the sheet in which your data is
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Output") 'the sheet where you want your result

LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set SearchRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 2), ws.Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

x = 2

For Each Cell In SearchRange
    Row = Cell.Row
    Column = Cell.Column
    If Cell.Value < 3 Then
        'Output is placed in 2 columns, A for time, B for date
        ws2.Cells(x, 1).Value = ws.Cells(1, Column).Value 'Copy-Paste Time
        ws2.Cells(x, 2).Value = ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value 'Copy-paste Date
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. It works without errors, but paste all dates, probably it's something wrong with formats. Trying to find solution.

Comment: ok, can you please mark this answer as the correct one then? thanks

Comment: Lambik, I am trying to modify one line to If Cell.Value < -3 Or Cell.Value >3 Then  But then I get all dates, maybe you know where can be the problem? It would be goot to see <-3 and >3.

Comment: please post the code you've written. if cell.value < -3 or cell.value > 3 then... should be correct.

Comment: I just changed this section, but it output all dates. Sum Outputs is "SUM" which is Z column. Maybe it search all sheet?

`For Each Cell In SearchRange
    Row = Cell.Row
    Column = Cell.Column
    If Cell.Value < -3 Or Cell.Value > 3 Then
        'Output is placed in 2 columns, A for date, B for time
        ws2.Cells(x, 1).Value = ws.Cells(Row, 1).Value 'Copy-paste Date
        ws2.Cells(x, 2).Value = ws.Cells(1, Column).Value 'Copy-Paste Time
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next Cell`

Comment: no, the code first searches the last used row and column and searches all cells between that cell and cell B2. I suggest you edit your answer and you include the FULL CODE (from sub to end sub) so I can check.

Comment: Edited on main question form.

Comment: I've ran the code with sample data and it does exactly as expected. What do you mean by "sum outputs is SUM which is Z column"?

Comment: I added two screens, maybe it will help you, 1 for output and second for more columns. I tested and then value >0 the output is all dates, times.

Comment: yes, the code starts looking for values as from cell B2 until the end of your range. It is thus interpreting the values in columns Z and AA as values to be checked against < -3 and > 3. It finds them as being TRUE, thus returning the corresponding value in row 1, here "sum" and "date". Specify the range in which the values are in order to correct for this.

Answer (score 0):

Open the excel, press ALT+F11 and on the left side window, right click on the Worksheet you use (The name of the Worksheet can be found there), select Add -> Modul, and copy the following code into.

When you adjusted the variables, just press the Play button, or press F5.

Here is your solution:

```
Sub Stackoverflow()

Dim wbk1 As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook

Rem Creating a new workbook to collect data
Set wbk1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)

Rem dc = datecolumn, the number of column AA
dc = Range("AA" & 1).Column

Rem k is the first row of new workbook, and i is the first row where the data can be found.
k = 1
i = 2

Do
  j = Range("AB" & 1).Column
  Do
    If wbk1.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(i, j).Value < 3 Then
      wbk2.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(k, 1) = wbk1.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(i, dc)
      wbk2.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(k, 2) = wbk1.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(1, j)
      wbk2.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(k, 3) = wbk1.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(i, j)
      k = k + 1
    End If
    j = j + 1
  Loop Until wbk1.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(i, j).Value = ""
  i = i + 1
Loop Until wbk1.Worksheets("Work1").Cells(i, j).Value = ""

Rem the result will be:
Rem first column in the new workbook will be the date
Rem second is the time
Rem third is the data

End Sub
```

Since you haven't provided the row numbers on your screen, you have to set the 'i' value to the first row where the data can be found. So if the row number is 2 where the number data are, just leave it so.

Please also note, you have to rename Work1 to the name of your Worksheet!

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

A faster way is using [powerquery](/questions/tagged/powerquery) (`Get & Transform Data`).

Format your source data as a `table`, then use a query like this:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Date"}, "Time", "Value"),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Unpivoted Other Columns", each [Value] < 3),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date", type date}, {"Time", type time}, {"Value", type number}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```